# Reactive Plots using Plotly

Tags: r, shiny

I want to make a reactive plot by using Plotly. When i click in a table row i want a modal to appear and to plot that specific element inside the modal. The plot show the appearences of each element in the datatable per day.

The original dataframe is:

```
> dput(head(closed_srs3))
structure(list(Name = c("DASOVOUNIX", "MYSTEGNA_X", "PETROCHORI_SAR", 
"AGNIK_SAR", "GARDIKI-X", "AMOELATOPOS"), Id = c(3311, 1632, 
4779, 4796, 4291, 1449), Date = structure(c(1548892800, 1548892800, 
1548892800, 1548892800, 1548892800, 1548460800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Created = structure(c(1548892800, 
1548892800, 1548892800, 1548892800, 1548892800, 1548460800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Closed = structure(c(1548979200, 1548979200, 
1548979200, 1548979200, 1548979200, 1548979200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The following works when the element's name is placed manually.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

myFrame <- data.frame(closed_srs3)

myFrame <- subset(myFrame, myFrame$Name == 'AGNIK_SAR')

newFrame <- myFrame %>%
  group_by(Name, Closed) %>%
  summarize(count = n())

p <- plot_ly(newFrame, x = newFrame$Closed, y = newFrame$count, type = 'bar')
```

The promblem is when i tried to make it reactive by using the following code, the plotted results were wrong. Can anyone help with that?

```
 # SUBITEM1 -> SRs
           tabItem(tabName = "SRs", 

            fluidRow(infoBoxOutput("progressBox")),       


        tabBox( width = 12,           
          tabPanel("All Closed SRs",
            column(3,
                selectInput(inputId="1", label= "Name", c("All", unique(as.character(closed_srs3$Name))))
                   ),
          column(3,
                selectInput(inputId="2", label= "Id", c('All', unique(as.character(closed_srs3$Id))))
                   ),
          column(3,
                selectInput(inputId="3", label= "Created", c('All', unique(as.character(closed_srs3$Created))))
                   ),
          column(3,
                selectInput(inputId="4", label= "Closed", c("All", unique(as.character(closed_srs3$Closed))))
                   ),


                          DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")),


          tabPanel("Wosrt Items by No of Appearences",    
            column(3,
                selectInput(inputId="5", label= "Name", c("All", unique(as.character(closed_srs3$Name))))
                   ),
            column(3,
                selectInput(inputId="6", label= "Id", c('All', unique(as.character(closed_srs3$Id))))
                   ),

                         DT::dataTableOutput(outputId="table2", width="100%")))


                               )# fluidrow
                      ) #tabItems
              ) #dashboardBody
) #dashboardPage


output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable(options = list(pageLength = 10),
                                       rownames= FALSE, server = FALSE, selection='single',

    {
      data<-closed_srs3 %>% count(Name, Id) %>%arrange(desc(n)

  if (input$`5` != "All") {
    data <- data[data$Name == input$`5`,]
  }

  if (input$`6` != "All") {
    data <- data[data$Id == input$`6`,]
  }

  data})
plotData<-reactive ({       
  s <- input$table2_rows_selected
  selectedName <- as.character(closed_srs3$Name[s])
  myFrame <- data.frame(closed_srs3)
  myFrame <- subset(myFrame, myFrame$Name == selectedName)

  newFrame <- myFrame %>%
    group_by(Name, Closed) %>%
    summarize(count = n())

  return(newFrame)  
  })

  observeEvent(input$table2_rows_selected,

    {showModal(modalDialog(
     title = "You have selected a row!", size = "l",
     output$plot1 <- renderPlotly(
     plot_ly( x = plotData()$Closed, y = plotData()$count, type = 'bar')

              ))) #showModal
              }) # observeEvent
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with the relevant UI code?

Comment: It would be better to include the UI in your question. And I think there's a parenthesis missing in your server code. And the subsetting results in an empty data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the plotted table is ordered differently than your reactive data. So you get a different result or probably always the same.

If you order the data.frame by Names in your reactive and your Table, it should be correct.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel("Wosrt Items by No of Appearences", 
           column(3,
                  selectInput(inputId="5", label= "Name", c("All", 
                                                            unique(as.character(closed_srs3$Name)))) ), 
           column(3, selectInput(inputId="6", label= "Id", c('All', 
                                                             unique(as.character(closed_srs3$Id)))) ), 
           DT::dataTableOutput(outputId="table2", width="100%"))
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data <- closed_srs3 %>% count(Name, Id)  %>% arrange(desc(n))

    if (input$`5` != "All") {
      data <- data[data$Name == input$`5`,]
    }

    if (input$`6` != "All") {
      data <- data[data$Id == input$`6`,]
    }

    data
  }, options = list(pageLength = 10),
  rownames= FALSE, server = FALSE, selection='single')

  plotData<-reactive({
    s <- input$table2_rows_selected

    ## Order the data the same way as the table !!!
    ordereddf <- closed_srs3 %>%  arrange(Name)
    selectedName <- as.character(ordereddf$Name[s])

    myFrame <- data.frame(closed_srs3)
    myFrame <- subset(myFrame, myFrame$Name == selectedName)

    newFrame <- myFrame %>%
      group_by(Name, Closed) %>%
      summarize(count = n())

    return(newFrame)  
  })

  observeEvent(input$table2_rows_selected, {
    req(plotData())
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "You have selected a row!", size = "l",
      output$plot1 <- renderPlotly(
        plot_ly( x = plotData()$Closed, y = plotData()$count, type = 'bar')

      ))) #showModal
  }) # observeEvent
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @ SeGa. thanks for the reply. Table2 is ordered by count. So the element with more counts (Name: PIKILOX with 55 counted appearences) is at first row. I want when i click on that element (PIKILOX) or the second, third etc a plot to appear with the appearences plotted against date (e.g 2 appearances on date x1, 4 on date x2, 3 on date x6 and so on). The previous code gives pretty match the same results as mine. Any thoughts?

Comment: The problem is that you're test data.frame is limited, so the count is only 1 for every Name and then it is ordered alphabtecially. You have to get the same order in the table and the reactive to plot the correct element.

Comment: I ordered it like that:   'ordereddf <- closed_srs3 %>%  count(Name, Id)  %>% arrange(desc(n))
    selectedName <- as.character(ordereddf$Name[s]) ' and wotks fine. Thanks again

Comment: Does that solve your problem? Or was there something else?